# Is there any way to include time-varying variables in CoxBoost or GLMBoost?

Tags: r, cox-regression, boosting

I am currently struggling with the following problem in R:

I would like to use a Cox model with time-varying variables to perform my variable selection via boosting. iCoxBoost takes a Surv object as formula which allows start-stop notation. But when I use it as follows

```
iCoxBoost(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ ., data=data)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in '[.default'(response, , "time") : subscript out of bounds

On the other hand `coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ ., data=data)` as well as `iCoxBoost(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data=data)` works fine.

Also, when I use GLMBoost I get for

```
glmboost(Surv(tstart,tstop,status) ~ ., data=data, family=CoxPH(), control=boost_control(mstop = 100))
```

the following error message:

> Error in basefit(u, m) : could not fit any base-learner in boosting iteration 19

On the other hand `glmboost(Surv(time,status) ~ ., data=data, family = CoxPH(), control=boost_control(mstop = 100))` works fine.

Are CoxBoost and GLMBoost simply not able to include time-variable variables, or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Addendum: I checked with the authors of the R packages; **CoxBoost (Version 1.4) and GLMBoost (Version 2.9-7) are indeed currently unable** to account for time-varying variables!

Comment: Could you provide a version number for those packages in case someone in the future finds this answer?